# Testing if email was sent in Kernel test

Tags: 8, emails, testing

I am trying to write automated tests for a or that will sent an email on submission.
I can write the test to check for the presence of the entity that is created along side the email, but I also want to have my automated test check that the system is sending an email too.

The examples I can find seem to relate to Laravel and the use of spies to see if a particular class method is called, however I can't find any examples of how to do that in Drupal 8 and in my particular use case I am using the function _user_mail_notify() and not a class method.

Does anyone have an example of testing that emails have seen sent at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at core tests that utilize email. For example:

- [`MailCaptureTest::testMailSend()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21FunctionalTests%21MailCaptureTest.php/function/MailCaptureTest%3A%3AtestMailSend/8.9.x)
- [`EmailActionTest::testEmailAction()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21Core%21Action%21EmailActionTest.php/function/EmailActionTest%3A%3AtestEmailAction/8.9.x)

The tests demonstrate ways to inspect the `plugin.manager.mail` service for signs that mail was successfully sent.